# WARNING : "SDK Version Issue". xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdk

when upload my app  with xcode 10.1 i'm getting the Warning

> WARNING ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 12.0 SDK. Starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later.

My project was developed in swift 4.2.1 and xcode 10.1

Comment: From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/) : "Update to Xcode 10.1, which includes the iOS 12.1 SDK, and build your apps. Starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store will need to be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, and support the all-screen design of iPhone XS Max or the 12.9-inch iPad Pro (3rd generation)."

Comment: thanks @tomerpacific but i use last version of xcode 10.1 !!

Comment: Sometimes Apple's site detects the wrong tool/SDK versions, especially when a new Xcode is released. If it was just a warning and you have succeeded to upload your app, just ignore it.

Comment: @OOPer I have Xcode 10.0 and I get the same alert. When I have clicked on "Done", I got in the archive screen "Uploaded with warnings". Will this block the publication or my build will be rejected?

Comment: @NeAS, I cannot assure you anything, but you need to use Xcode 10.1 (or later) to submit apps staring March 2019, to follow the Apple's requirement noted in  tomerpacific's comment. If your Mac is capable of running Xcode 10.1, I strongly recommend you to update your Xcode immediately.

Comment: @OOPer the publication was not blocked. But as you said, it's recommended to update the Xcode version to 10.1 from now. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: In my case, I got the same issue but as an "App Store Connection Operation Error", I too use the XCode 10.1. What could be the issue ?

Comment: do we know if this is March 1st?  By the end of March?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Make sure you have the latest version of Xcode.**

If you do have **Xcode 10.1** (or later) this is just a reminder that all of your apps need to comply with these terms.

Also regardless of Xcode version if your app did archive/build successfully you have nothing to worry about at the moment.

**EDIT:**

**Now ALL APPS and GAMES submitted to the AppStore must have the 12.1 SDK or they will be rejected.**

If your app is still rejected and you have **Xcode 10.1** (or later), update Xcode or reinstall, as the SDK was not integrated correctly by the system.

Comment: It is currently March and I getting this error with Xcode 10.1.  I even tried reinstalling it from the store and always get this on upload of my build.  I get an email about it and my builds are unavailable in iTunesConnect.  Is anyone else still running in to this issue?

Comment: "Version 10.1 (10B61)" - should be the same one that's live on the App Store

Comment: What is the highest level of iOS you support?

Comment: My deployment target is 11.0 but I still get the issue when I target 12.1

Comment: I suggest you take it up with apple and/or creating a question here on stack overflow. Sorry I couldn’t be of more help

Comment: No worries, thank you for trying!  I'll start a new question

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you're running a CI/CD pipeline/workflow (such as Bitrise), make sure you've updated the Xcode version in the tool's Stack as well.
In my case, my local version was correct but the Xcode version in my pipeline referenced 10.0 rather than 10.1

Answer (score 1):

This trick worked for me:
Download Xcode 10.2, extract and just copy(iPhoneOS12.2.sdk Folder):
or direct download zip : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZGANCBE90Ogt4FD_y_ACgcIFP0qQapSf/view?usp=sharing

Right click->Show Package Contents->Contents->Developer->Platforms->iPhoneOS.platform->Developer->SDKs->iPhoneOS12.2.sdk
and past it same directory on your Xcode.
after this close your Xcode, reopen Xcode , Archive and upload again.

Comment: Thank you! This seems the solution to my problem, but can I download the iPhoneOS12.2.sdk folder somewhere? I cannot download Xcode 10.2 as it's incompatible with my macOS.

Comment: sdk10.2 link:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZGANCBE90Ogt4FD_y_ACgcIFP0qQapSf/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall Xcode 10.1 and re-install it.