# Setting SDK to 12.1

Tags: xcode, sdk, app-store

I keep getting the warning:

> This app was built with the iOS 11.4 SDK. Starting March 2019, all iOS
>   apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or
>   later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later.

...when I upload to the app store.

I run Xcode 10.1, and I also set the base SDK to 12.1 as in the screenshot, but I still get the warning after archiving and uploading. Is there anything else I need to do? Deployment target is 9.0.

[image]

Comment: Three ideas to start with.  Does it happen if you increase a major in Deployment target?  Are you using multiple Xcode versions simultaneously?  Do you have still the old SDK installed?  Try to uninstall it completely (there maybe issues with paths, etc.)

Comment: Please check or upload your complete build log. It should show the SDK version used.

Comment: check this: [WARNING : “SDK Version Issue”. xcode 10.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786309/warning-sdk-version-issue-xcode-10-1)

Comment: Do you have any issues preventing your app from using the latest SDK ? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1806/_index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you are using latest version of Xcode for compiling and uploading your build. Also make sure that you app screens support the all-screen design of iPhone XS Max or the 12.9-inch iPad Pro (3rd generation). Also check if all the pods are also build on latest SDK

I had 2 versions of Xcode (9 and 10) on my machine and after uploading I was also getting this warning. May be lame but once I removed Xcode 9 from my machine this warning went away.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is just a workaround. I'm not sure it can solve your problem.*

Your Base SDK setting is different from mine.

Since I have just uploaded my app to Appstore without any problem (Nov 13, 2018 at 10:23 PM),

I think it's worth a try to set it to `iphoneos` like in the image and try to archive and upload again.

[image]
*Xcode version 10.1 (10B61)*